# Single query to return one to many by a search on the many

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I've got a table like this

```
Table1Id | Column2
-------------------
100      | somedata
```

And one like this

```
Table2Id|Table1Id|Name  |Value
-------------------------------
500     |100     |name1 |value1
501     |100     |name2 |value2
```

I have "name1" and "value1" to search with and I want to retrieve everything from table1 with it. That's easy but how to retrieve the rest of the children in table2 when I've only got the data from the first row? I want to do it in a single query and I wanted to avoid subqueries but not sure if that's possible.

Can someone fix this query to return the other child row in table2?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.Table1Id = t2.Table1Id
WHERE t2.Name = 'name1' AND t2.Value = 'value1'
```

Comment: You mention _"the other child row in table2"_ but don't show it in your question... Try a `FULL OUTER JOIN` if you want all records from both tables

Comment: @dvo The other child is in the second table. A full outer join won't work because of the Where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select T1.*, T2.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 on T1.Table1Id = T2.Table1Id
INNER JOIN Table2 Query on T1.id= Query.Table1Id
WHERE Query.[Name] = 'name1' AND Query.[Value] = 'value1'
```

Note that this will not throw an error if there are more than 1 `Table2` rows with the same combination of `Name` and `Value`.

Comment: In that case you probably want `select T1.*, T2.*` to avoid repeating Table2's columns.

Comment: Unfortunately though, while a totally valid solution, in the absence of any indexes, my query performs twice as well as yours :)

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot. Edited :D

I just offered an alternative solution that avoids subqueries. Perhaps the combination of name and value isnt unique which would benefit from indexing.
In the absence of any indexes I would probably recommend adding them as it seems these tables have a clear relationship :)

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why you want to avoid sub-queries in this instance a sub-query provides the best performance e.g.

```
declare @Table1 table (Table1Id int, Column2 varchar(32));
declare @Table2 table (Table2Id int, Table1Id int, [Name] varchar(32), [Value] varchar(32));

insert into @Table1 (Table1Id, Column2)
  select 100, 'somevalue1' union all
  select 101, 'somevalue2'

insert into @Table2 (Table2Id, Table1Id, [Name], [Value])
  select 500, 100, 'name1', 'value1' union all
  select 501, 100, 'name2', 'value2' union all
  select 502, 101, 'name3', 'value3' union all
  select 503, 101, 'name4', 'value4'

SELECT *
FROM @Table1 T1
INNER JOIN @Table2 T2 on T1.Table1Id = T2.Table1Id
WHERE T1.Table1Id = (
  SELECT T2A.Table1Id
  FROM @Table2 T2A
  WHERE T2A.[Name] = 'name1' AND T2A.[Value] = 'value1'
)
```

Gives:

```
Table1Id    Column2     Table2Id    Table1Id    Name    Value
100         somevalue1  500         100         name1   value1
100         somevalue1  501         100         name2   value2
```

Comment: What with the trying to avoid a sub-query anyway? They are a staple part of any T-SQL toolbox.

Comment: I was just curious if I could do it. I would have taken your answer but I've got a clustered index on value,name

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for, not at all sure:

```
select *
from Table2 t2
left join Table1 t1 on t1.Table1Id = t2.Table1Id
and t2.Name = 'name1' and t2.Value = 'value1'
```